# Creating and saving a text file on a server every day through a C# console application

Tags: c#, ftp, windows-server-2003

I have developed a `C# console application` which I scheduled it on a windows server which runs every morning and creates a text file in a folder named `FTP` in `C drive` of the server with some data retrieved from `SQL server` and this file will be accessed by some outside users using `FTP`. I have used the following code

```
 FileStream fs = File.Create("test.txt");

            int i = 0;
            StreamWriter sw = null;

            sw = new StreamWriter("C:\FTP\test.txt", false);
            for (i = 0; i < dtlist.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                sw.Write(dtlist.Columns[i].ColumnName + "\t");
            }
            sw.Write(dtlist.Columns[i].ColumnName);
            sw.WriteLine();


            foreach (DataRow row in dtlist.Rows)
            {
                object[] array = row.ItemArray;

                for (i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    sw.Write(array[i].ToString() + "\t");
                }
                sw.Write(array[i].ToString());
                sw.WriteLine();
            }

            sw.Close();
```

As we can see that I have directly given the file path on the server as I scheduled this application on the server itself and I wonder if this the right approach or if I should better user the server address `10.0.0.10` as the destination and create a file.

**May I know a better way if there is any?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is probably more a code review question rather than stack overflow...

Personally, Id not hard code the resulting filename, but have it as a parameter, so if you have to move it, thats fine no re-coding required.  You could consider FTP'ing the file to the server, however, then you get into the realms of securely storing usernames and passwords potentially, but it is a consideration.

Comment: Thanks and yeah I had the filename as parameter and passing it while calling the function, I just hard coded it in the question